# mypy Union[Fraction,int] weird inference behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

Consider the following code (in Python 3.7, mypy 0.770):

```
from typing import Union
from fractions import Fraction
import math

def f(a: Union[Fraction, int]) -> Union[Fraction, int]:
    reveal_type(a) # Revealed type is 'Union[fractions.Fraction, builtins.int]'
    reveal_type(math.pi) # Revealed type is 'builtins.float'
    return math.pi*a
```

mypy gives the following error on the last line:

`Incompatible return value type (got "Union[Any, float]", expected "Union[Fraction, int]")`

This does not seem like correct behaviour to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: This seems like a similar issue: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8601

Comment: The return type should just be `float` in any case, no? Whether `a` is a `Fraction` or an `int`, `math.pi*a` is a `float`.

Comment: yeah, but I don't know if mypy is smart enough to realise that

Comment: If you use `f(a: Union[...]) -> float:`, the error goes away. Are you looking for a solution, or an explanation for the `Union[Any, float]` that appears in the error message?

Comment: ahh, yeah, I see the mistake now, thanks! I still don't understand why mypy wants the return type to be `Union[Any, float]` though, instead of just `float`.